# My database is replaced with a new database . is there a way to get the old database back?

Tags: mysql, database

My database is replaced with a new database . is there a way to get the old database back ?

Comment: What Database Server are you using, describe your scenario more.

Comment: Restore from backup.

Comment: Please review how to write a good question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Following the details on that page and editing this question may help you get the answer you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hosted on a cPanel server then it's pretty normal for daily, weekly and monthly backups to be taken. These backups contain everything, this includes your MySQL databases. I would get in touch with your host asap and see whether they have anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you have the old database file. Do you have it or a backup?

Comment: databases are files, files can be undeleted